# I have a Git repository. I have cloned the repository,Commited my local changes. When I push my changes to the server it shows error

Tags: tortoisegit

when i pull the chages from clone, it is reflected in server and vice versa. but when i push it shows error.

Error message:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 474 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To //INCHNLRDFS06/CUB Ebanking$/GIT_Ebank
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '//INCHNLRDFS06/CUB Ebanking$/GIT_Ebank'

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1029 ms @ 9/10/2014 6:43:09 PM)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you talk about the error ?

Comment: i have posted the screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning from another user's repository, the `origin` remote (assuming you're pushing to `origin`) is linked to that user's repo.

In order to commit and push your changes, you first must fork that user's repo and clone from your fork. Doing so will set up your remote to your repo and you can commit and push as you please.

You can view your remotes in the `.git/config` file and correct them if you're still having trouble.

Comment: thank you for helping me,fork means exactly what i have to do